# Inner product is invariant under reflections in the real hyperplane?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthogonality, reflection

Let $V$ be an (even) finite-dimensional vector space. I’m trying to prove that $$d(r_v(u), r_v(w))=d(u,w),$$ where $d:V \times V \to \mathbb{R}$ is a positive definite symmetric bilinear form (i.e. a real scalar product on $V$, $v$ is a unit vector (that is, that $d(v,v)=1$) and $$r_v(u)=2d(u,v)v-u.$$ Notice that $-r_v$ is the reflection in the real hyperplane orthogonal to $v$. In particular, $r_v^2=1$.

The problem is that when I compute $d(r_v(u),r_v(w))$ I get $$d(r_v(u),2d(v,w)v)+d(2d((v,w)v,-u)+d(u,w)=d(2d(u,v)v,r_v(w)+d(2d(v,w)v,-w)+d(u,w).$$ I fill like I’m close, but, how do I prove that $$d(r_v(u),2d(v,w)v)+d(2d((v,w)v,-u))=0= d(2d(u,v)v,r_v(w)+d(2d(v,w)v,-w)?$$ Any ideas?? :(

Comment: Are you sure your formula for $r_v(u)$ is what you want? Based on you saying that $-r_u$ is the reflection across the hyperplane with unit normal $u$, I would think that $-r_u(v) = v - 2d(v, u)u$.

Comment: @Mason You’re right. That’s a typo. I’m going to correct it right away. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every vector $x$ can be decomposed into the sum of two components, $x_v=d(x,v)v$ and $x_{v^\perp}=x-d(x,v)v$, where $x_v$ is parallel to $v$, and $x_{v^\perp}$ is $d$-orthogonal to $v$ because
$$
d(v,x_{v^\perp})
=d\big(v,x-d(x,v)v\big)
=d(v,x)-d(x,v)d(v,v)=0.
$$
It follows that $d(u_v,w_{v^\perp})=d(u_{v^\perp},w_v)=0$.
Now note that $r_v(x)=x_v-x_{v^\perp}$. Therefore
$$
\begin{aligned}
d\big(r_v(u),r_v(w)\big)
&=d\big(u_v-u_{v^\perp},\,w_v-w_{v^\perp}\big)\\
&=d(u_v,w_v)
-d(u_v,w_{v^\perp})
-d(u_{v^\perp},w_v)
+d(u_{v^\perp},w_{v^\perp})\\
&=d(u_v,w_v)
+d(u_v,w_{v^\perp})
+d(u_{v^\perp},w_v)
+d(u_{v^\perp},w_{v^\perp})\\
&=d\big(u_v+u_{v^\perp},\,w_v+w_{v^\perp}\big)\\
&=d(u,w).
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! That’s exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

$r_v(u) = 2d(u,v)v-u$,
$$d(r_v(u),r_v(w)) = d(2d(u,v)v-u,2d(w,v)v-w)$$
$$ = -1 \times  d(u,2d(w,v)v-w) + 2d(u,v) \times  d(v,2d(w,v)v-w)$$
$$ = -1 \times  (2d(u,v)\times d(w,v) - d(u,w))  + 2d(u,v) \times  (2d(w,v)-d(v,w))$$
$$ = -2d(u,v)\times d(w,v) + d(u,w)  + 2d(u,v) \times  2d(w,v)- 2d(u,v) \times d(v,w)$$
$$ = d(u,v)$$
The last step used symmetry of $d$ and third step we used $d(v,v)=1$.